# Is it possible to install the MobileFirst Platform JSONStore Cordova plugin without any other MobileFirst plugins?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ibm-mobilefirst, ionic2, jsonstore

I'm building an Ionic 2 app where the only MFP 8 feature I currently need is the JSONStore. Is it possible to install only the MFP JSONStore Cordova plugin, and not any of the other MFP Cordova plugins?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the open source edition of JSONStore, however note that it is not supported by our support team: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/blog/2016/04/01/using-security-in-jsonstore/

You can find the source and instructions in the plug-in's GitHub page: https://github.com/ibm-bluemix-mobile-services/jsonstore-cordova

To add the plug-in: `cordova plugin add https://github.com/ibm-bluemix-mobile-services/jsonstore-cordova`